# Consume WP rest api in Java

Tags: java, wordpress, oauth

I am trying consume OAuth 1.0a from wordpress using the plugin "WP REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server" in a Java Swing application.

Following the instructions of this link (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-oauth-10a-authentication--cms-24797) using PostMan, it works.

I try to do the same in Java with this code, but it does not work and I do not understand why.

```
    OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(client_id, client_secret);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    String urlRequest = jsonObjectAuth.getJSONObject("oauth1").getString("request");
    String urlAuthorize = jsonObjectAuth.getJSONObject("oauth1").getString("authorize");
    String urlAccess = jsonObjectAuth.getJSONObject("oauth1").getString("access");

    /*
    *
    *   Step 1
    *
    * */

    urlRequest = oAuthConsumer.sign(urlRequest);
    System.out.print("\nURLRequest: " + urlRequest);
    HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(urlRequest);

    //oAuthConsumer.sign(httpGetRequest);

    HttpResponse httpResponseRequest = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
    int codigoRespuesta = httpResponseRequest.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    String responseRequestString = null;

    if (codigoRespuesta == 200) {
        responseRequestString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(httpResponseRequest);
        System.out.print("\n" + responseRequestString);
    } else {
        System.out.print("\nRequest: " + httpResponseRequest.getStatusLine().toString());
        return;
    }

    /*
    *
    *   Step 2
    *
    * */

    urlAuthorize = urlAuthorize + "/?" +responseRequestString;
    System.out.print("\nURL para authorize: " + urlAuthorize);
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(urlAuthorize));


    /*
    *
    *   Step 3
    *
    * */

    String oauth_verifier = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(jFrame, "Coloque aquí el token de verificación obtenido en el navegador","Token de verificación",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    urlAccess = urlAccess + "/?" + responseRequestString + "&oauth_verifier=" + oauth_verifier;
    urlAccess = oAuthConsumer.sign(urlAccess);
    System.out.print("\nURLAccess: " + urlAccess);
```

When I open generated URLAccess, I receive "OAuth signature does not match"

I do not understand why.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: PostMan shared cookie with browser so only its work, I think your Auth not working properly.

Comment: Might worth to consider [java api v2 client](https://github.com/Afrozaar/wp-api-v2-client-java) library